# Is there an idiom that means that someone has an advantage over you in a fight or competition?

Tags: idiom-request

Is there an idiom that means that someone has an advantage over you in a fight or competition?

I can think of "I have the higher ground", but I can't think of anything else. I don't like this, because it sounds like the person has the higher ground and is standing on the higher ground as in "Anakin, I have the higher ground", so is there anything else I can use? And this can lead to confusion if you're not a native speaker with a thick accent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

["I have the upper hand"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/211378) is a good way to communicate this concept unambiguously.

Some of the other answers on [Is there an idiom that means that you are in a very strong negotiation position in a negotiation?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/211368/140174) would be related, but there's two categories:

- I physically have the advantage
- I mentally and strategically have the advantage

It sounds like you're trying to communicate a physical advantage, so other good candidates would be:

- ["I have you over the barrel in this fight"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/211374/140174)
- ["I am in the driver's seat of this fight"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/211387/140174)
- ["I have leverage over you in this fight"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/211389/140174)

Comment: Also, "to have an edge (over someone)"

Comment: It's "over **a** barrel", and "to be in the driver's seat **in** this fight".